# Why are weird encoded characters in my string?

Tags: python, string, encoding

I am fetching a string from a website and it is returning the string with some sort of weird charachters in it

`Pok&#233;mon &#38; Magic the Gathering`

How can I easily convert it to say Pokémon & in stead of using .replace('é', é) because there are other sorts of weird characters like it that aren't é.

Sorry if my question is worded poorly I don't really understand why this is happening to begin with, any help is appreciated

Comment: It is a product name from a website I retrieve from a json.

Comment: `chr(233) == 'é'` looks like ascii codes

Comment: In any case, those look to be html "entities". See the linked duplicate for a built-in way to decode them

Comment: @jakub okay, how can I decode it?

Comment: @JeffreyLim again, look at the linked duplicate, but basically, `import html` then use `html.unescape(s)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga would you do that *before* or *after* the JSON decoding?  I'm guessing before but I've never had to do it.

Comment: @MarkRansom probably after deserializing the json would be safer, but I don't really understand how the OP is getting the string.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just a guess, the source is generating the JSON then sending it to a generic output function that does HTML encoding.  Then whatever OP is using to read it does *not* do decoding.

Comment: @MarkRansom ah, yes, that sounds likely